# Adding custom field to type class other than corresponding model class in GraphQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

```
module Types
  class PaymentType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, Integer, null: false
    field :amount, Integer, null: false
    field :currency, String, null: false
    field :xyz, Integer, null: true
  end
end
```

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
    field :id, Integer, null: false
    field :amount, Integer, null: false
    field :currency, String, null: false
end
```

```
module Mutations
  class CreatePayment < BaseMutation

    type Types::PaymentType
    description "Create Payment"

    argument :amount, Integer, required: true
    argument :currency, String, required: true

    def resolve(amount: , currency: )
      payment = Payment.new(amount: amount, currency: currency)
      xyz = SomeXYZ()
      payment.save
      payment
    end
  end
end
```

Here I have an additional field in PaymentType compared to corresponding model. In the resolver of my mutation, i want to fetch the data for xyz and return a PaymentType with this xyz included in it apart from payment.

I have tried appending xyz to payment variable only, but every time i get some or the other error.
I have also tried to create a constructor for PaymentType but it also gives error.

```
module Types
  class PaymentType < Types::BaseObject
    field :id, Integer, null: false
    field :amount, Integer, null: false
    field :currency, Integer, null: false
    field :xyz, Integer, null: true

    def initialize(payment, xyz)
      self.id = payment.id
      self.amount = payment.amount
      self.currency = payment.currency
      self.xyz = xyz
    end
  end
end
```

I am relatively new in GraphQL and rails. It would be really helpful if someone could suggest here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be following your idea correctly, as I'm not sure what `Xyz` represents, but I suspect you could be implementing the structure in some other way:

```rb
module Mutations
  class CreatePayment < BaseMutation

    type Types::PaymentType
    description "Create Payment"

    argument :amount, Integer, required: true
    argument :currency, String, required: true

    def resolve(amount: , currency: )
      payment = Payment.new(amount: amount, currency: currency)
      xyz = SomeXYZ()
      payment.save

      {
        payment: payment, # or just `payment:` in new hash format
        xyz: xyz          # or just `xyz:` in new hash format
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One more way i found: payment.attributes.merge({xyz: xyz}). 
Thanks Pipetus for your help!!